# Quickblox QMServices vs QMResponse

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

Could someone explain the difference between logging in with Quickblox's service API

```
QMServicesManager.instance().logInWithUser
```

Compared with the standard API call to login:

```
QBRequest.logInWithUserEmail()
```

I want to login with facebook, but it seems I have to call the following function:

```
QBRequest.logInWithSocialProvider()
```

Which logs in with facebook and then returns a user then the services API

```
QMServicesManager.instance().logInWithUser
```

This seems as though it logs into Quickblox twice however there is no login with social provider in the services api.

Answer (score 2):

QBRequest is basic requests implementation from Quickblox iOS SDK. It contains plain method and you can use them in any way you want to.
QMServicesManager is a singleton class of QMServices project: https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-services-ios

It is basically a wrapper over QBRequest methods + caching. It has a lot of utilities for your needs.

You can read about QMServices project on its Github page.

Comment: But it seems limited in functionality, for example how would I log a user in using facebook?

I'd have to use the SDK to get the user back and then login using QMServices which just doesn't seem right.

Comment: There is method for facebook login in QMServices too, check QMAuthService class.

Comment: Ah so there is thanks! And how might I login to the chat service once I have already logged in to QuickBlox.

When I try and get the current user from QMServices and login to chat it use the QBUUser passed back it complains the password is wrong.

Comment: Use 'connect' method of QMChatService. Also checkout their README file on Github. It is basically contains every method explanation.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've basically ported your QMAPI wrapper for these from objective C to swift for my project.

What I can't get my head around however is I keep getting when trying to connect to chat - Not Authorised, even after calling the login service from QMAuthService?

Comment: Refer to q-municate-services-ios repository with some logs or create a separate question for these with logs included.